# std::ref implicit conversion to reference confusion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion, ref, reference-wrapper

I know that a std::ref(object) creates a std::reference_wrapper(object), and that std::reference_wrapper has a non-explicit type conversion operator member function

```
operator T&() const
```

and I know that this influences how I use it when template parameter deduction comes into play:
so in Print below, the type T of the argument is deduced as std::reference_wrapper if I call it with,say, std::ref("hello")

```
template <class T>
void Print(T t)
{
    std::cout << t << std::end;
}
```

Why doesn't this line compile?

```
std::string s = "hello";
std::cout << std::reference_wrapper<std::string>(s) << std::endl;
```

the instantiated specialization should have a

```
operator std::string&() const
```

type conversion function, so why can't I use a reference wrapper like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator<<` overload that you are trying to use has the following form (from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)):

> ```
> template <class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator>
>
> std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
>     operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os,
>                const std::basic_string<CharT, Traits, Allocator>& str);
> ```

The second function parameter contains template parameters and is not a non-deduced context. Therefore it must deduce the template arguments. Implicit conversions are not considered for template argument deduction and since `std::reference_wrapper` is not a `std::basic_string`, deduction will fail. It doesn't matter whether `std::reference_wrapper` can be converted to `std::string` (or a reference to one).

And just to clarify, `std::string` is an alias for the specialization `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>` of `std::basic_string`. `std::basic_string` can be specialized for any character type, for example `wchar_t` (which is aliased as `std::wstring`). Other specializations are simply not often used.